# Refreshing part of page ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web page using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework and I'm looking for a way to refresh a part in my .cshtml page (A div, for example) every certain amount of time.

What is the simpliest way of doing that?
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at partial views and you will need to look into Ajax as well for the client

Comment: JQuery and use Ajax.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/partial-view-in-mvc/

Comment: Take a look at SignalR as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to manipulate the dom is with jquery. do look at ajax
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Controller/Method/",
        data: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#divid").html(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Something may be wrong. The `success` mean: Replace the content of `#divid` with `response`, does not `refresh` anything.

Comment: You can use setInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval to invoke the above method periodically ie. setInterval(function(){$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Controller/Method/",
        data: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#divid").html(response);
        }
    });}, 5000)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#content").load("My_page_here.php");
  });
});
```